# Behaviour like fillRect with arc

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I would like to have the same behaviour as can be [seen here](https://codepen.io/travisholliday/pen/gyaJk) for a rectangle for a circle. 
So i would like to draw for example a halfCircle and i want to fill the area encapsulated between the two lines dynamically.

It might look like this were the green color should be filled dynamically based on some actions:

[image: sample half circle]

So i would like to be able to set that only half of the height of this halfcirlce is filled with color, then 70% etc... like a progressbar for example.

I tried it like this:

```
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.arc(centerCoordinate.x, centerCoordinate.y, circleRadius, 0, Math.PI, false);

    var cirlceEndpoint = getCircleEndPoint(centerCoordinate, Math.PI);
    ctx.lineTo(cirlceEndpoint[0] + 20, cirlceEndpoint[1]);
    ctx.moveTo(centerCoordinate.x + circleRadius, centerCoordinate.y);

    ctx.arc(centerCoordinate.x, centerCoordinate.y, circleRadius - 20, 0, Math.PI, false);
    ctx.moveTo(centerCoordinate.x + circleRadius, centerCoordinate.y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.stroke();
```

But with this the whole halfCircle is filled and not only the area between the lines.

How could i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply the correct `anticlockwise` flag to the [`arc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) function:

```js
// Draw arc segment with given inner and outer radius and start and end angle:
function drawArc(ctx, x, y, inner, outer, start, end) {
  if (start > end) [end, start] = [start, end];

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, outer, start, end, false);
  if (end < start + 2 * Math.PI) {
    ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(end) * inner, y + Math.sin(end) * inner);
  } else {
    ctx.moveTo(x + Math.cos(end) * inner, y + Math.sin(end) * inner);
  }
  ctx.arc(x, y, inner, end, start, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Example:
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function frame(time) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawArc(ctx, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 40, 60, 0, time * 0.001);
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}
requestAnimationFrame(frame);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```